# How do I do a search in the bing image window from the url?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, search, bing, google-image-search

search from url
how do i search here !? search from url with picture url in bing image search
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaUJO.jpg)
enable search with image url, from the url in the same place that appears in the image

normlly in google lens we use this link https://lens.google.com/uploadbyurl?url=<image_url>
how can i use bing image search like this type of link please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```py
import urllib.parse

url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaUJO.jpg"
encoded_url = urllib.parse.quote(url, safe='')
url = "https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailv2&iss=sbi&q=imgurl:"+ encoded_url
```